# Make pandas.read_csv() ignore junk at the start of the csv files?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I've got some junk at the start of my csv file that prevents me selecting the first column of my dataframe by name.

Example:

```
In[1]: df = pd.read_csv('file:inputdata.csv', usecols=[0], nrows=1)

In[2]: df
Out[2]:
        TAB
0  10-LV_Non

In[3]: df['TAB']
Out[3]: <snip> KeyError: 'TAB'
```

I found the junk by reading the file with open():

```
In[4]: with open('inputdata.csv', 'rb') as f:
           print(f.read(7))
Out[4]: b'\xef\xbb\xbfTAB,'
```

EDIT: `'\xef\xbb\xbf'` is three bytes of junk. `'TAB'` is the name of the first column.

Is there a way to make `pandas.read_csv()` ignore junks like this (if present) at the start of the csv file?

NB The csv files are exported from a proprietary system, so I can't control their format.

UPDATE: Here's my solution, based on Mike Müller's answer:

```
with open('inputdata.csv', 'r') as f:
    # Skip past any bytes that aren't text
    while re.match('[a-zA-Z0-9_]', f.read(1)) is None:
        pass
    # Seek back one byte
    f.seek(f.tell()-1)
    # Read the file
    df = pd.read_csv(f, usecols=['TAB'])
```

Answer (score 3):

It's unclear to me what exactly is the format of the "junk", but there are a number of options to use.

---

[`pandas.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) takes a `filepath_or_buffer`

> filepath_or_buffer : string or file handle / StringIO

It follows that if you `open` a [`File` object](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/bltin-file-objects.html), read past the junk, then pass the `File` object to `read_csv`, it should be OK.

---

The `skiprows` arguments skips rows:

> skiprows : list-like or integer, default None

Thus you can possibly skip the junk's row(s).

Comment: skiprows is the way to go

Answer (score 2):

Something like this could work:

```
with open('inputdata.csv', 'rb') as f:
    if f.read(7) != b'\xef\xbb\xbfTAB,':
        f.seek(0)
    df = pd.read_csv(f, usecols=[0], nrows=1)
```

Just read the first seven bytes. If the are good, i.e. not equal to the bytes you don't want, go back to the beginning of the file with `seek(0)`, otherwise start reading at position 7 bytes, skipping the offending bytes.